# Show tables where I am not granted access in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to list table and column names where I am not granted access? I am a developer trying to access and see if a column name is available but dba's are restricting any sort of read 'select' access. This is for SQL Server 2008. Thanks.

Comment: Can you access the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views?

Comment: Talk to your dba.

Comment: Yes, I can but the view only lists the tables I can see. I am pretty sure there are more tables which I cannot see.

Comment: Why do you want to find the names of tables and columns that you don't have access to?

Comment: Not my use case, but users are usually given access to adhoc query tools. However they are not given access to database tables. As a user, I might know that it is being captured but I'd like to check or search which table or column being captured. I might want to run my own query which I cannot since I am not given access. There might be things, adhoc db tool might not create such as complex sql. Why limit people? When you take freedom away in the name of security, I am opposed to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. The SQL Server will not expose any metadata on objects you dont have a privilege to use. So, if you don't have a SELECT permission on a table, you won't see it's metadata. Same with stored procedures etc.

Comment: Dominion of DBAs who restrict everything and claim such a thing is not available. No way to disprove.

Answer (score 3):

It would be best to open up communications with your DBA for this issue. Technically speaking there is a way to do this however the DBA is likely the only one that can provide this information. Which asking what you have permissions to is not an unreasonable request in my eyes (as a DBA).

You might also suggest that in place of you having to ask them these types of questions over and over if they can grant you `VIEW DEFINITION` on the particular database. This grants you metadata access to objects in the database without granting access to the objects themselves.

Comment: What is a DBA's favorite word?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='<name>'
```

Not sure if the DBA's restricted access to these views or not

Comment: I can access those views but result I get back is the only tables I can view.